# Get multiple items from Cocoa NSOutlineView using selectedIndexSet in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsoutlineview

When I need to get the selected item from a NSOutlineView I can just use this:

```
func item(atRow row: Int) -> Any?
```

But how do I get a list of items when using multiple selections?
I can use

```
var selectedRowIndexes: IndexSet { get }
```

to get an IndexSet but isn't there an implemented way to get an array of the selected items?

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map` the rows to the items, `compactMap` unwraps the optionals safely.

```
let selectedItems = outlineView.selectedRowIndexes.compactMap{outlineView.item(atRow: $0)}
```

`outlineView` is the reference to the `NSOutlineView`

The result is an array of `Any`. You can cast the type either in the closure or at the end of the line.